# Wordpress Dropdown - add Arrow

Tags: css, wordpress, dropdown

I want to add an *(CSS?)*-arrow like this below to my Wordpress-generated dropdown sub-menu.

[image]

Is there any way to do this?

If you need further information, ask please.

Regards

Comment: What have you tried to do to make this happen? What is the specific problem you are having? This isn't a place where you can just have people write code for you. This is a place to get help on code you're writing.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to start here. My wp_nav_menu() function does everything for me and I don't know what to change to achieve something like it's shown in the image.

Comment: the `wp_nav_menu` function doesn't do everything. All it gives you is the structure and content. You have to use CSS to change anything like layout, color, sizes, position... I would suggest googling for how to style dropdown menus for a good starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS3 we can make shapes. Not all shapes will render correctly in all browsers, currently only web browsers that support CSS3 will work.

Here's the markup.

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    ...
</ul>
```

Here's the style.

```
.sub-menu {
    position: relative;
}
.sub-menu:after {
    content: '';
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-bottom: 120px solid blue; 
    border-left: 60px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 60px solid transparent; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 25px;
    transform: translate(0, -100%);
}
```

You might find this helpful as well - http://www.cssportal.com/css3-shapes/

Comment: I edited your answer to be more WP specific and to use a pseudo element.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too sure about WordPress but with CSS you can configure something like this:

```
.buttonArrow:hover
  {
    background: url(blue-arrow.png);
  }
```

The idea is that on hover (or on clicking the dropdown), the arrow image pops up. I'm not sure if there's a way to do it easily on WordPress. You'd have to match the color of the arrow and the color of the dropdown, in this case, blue.

/u/jarmerson's answer is good as well. You can also try looking at SVG in [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/default.asp) for more shapes.

Comment: And then someone changes the dropdown color and what happens? A pseudo element with a CSS triangle is much better.

Comment: Yeah I included /u/jarmerson's answer for a pseudo element as a good (even better) solution.